# How do you use errors.add_to_base outside of the validates_ or validate_ model methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Course class that has many WeightingScales and I am trying to get the WeightingScales validation to propagate through the system.  The short of the problem is that the following code works except for the fact that the errors.add_to_base() call doesn't do anything (that I can see).  The Course object saves just fine and the WeightingScale objects fail to save, but I don't ever see the error in the controller.

```
  def weight_attributes=(weight_attributes)
    weighting_scales.each do |scale|
      scale.weight = weight_attributes.fetch(scale.id.to_s).fetch("weight")

      unless scale.save
        errors.add_to_base("The file is not in CSV format")
      end
    end
  end
```

My question is similar to this [1](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/61283): How can you add errors to a Model without being in a "validates" method?

[link text](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/61283)

Comment: When you say propagate through the system, do you mean you want to see the weighting scale errors on the course model when you try to save it?

Comment: Yes, I want the Course model to show the errors when I try to save it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the save to fail, you'll need to use a validate method. If not, you'll have to use callbacks like before_save or before_create to check that errors.invalid? is false before you allow the save to go through. Personally, i'll just use validate. Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to validate a parameter that never needed to be saved to the model (just a confirmation flag).

If I did:

```
@user.errors.add_to_base('You need to confirm') unless params[:confirmed]
if @user.save
  # yay
else
  # show errors
end
```

it didn't work. I didn't delve into the source but from playing around in the console it looked like calling `@user.save` or `@user.valid?` cleared `@user.errors` before running the validations.

My workaround was to do something like:

```
if @user.valid? && params[:confirmed]
  @user.save
  # redirect to... yay!
elsif !params[:confirmed]
  @user.errors.add_to_base('You need to confirm')
end
# show errors
```

Errors added to base after validations have been run stick around and display correctly in the view.

But this is a little different to your situation as it looks like you want to add errors in a setter not a controller action. You might want to look into before_validation or after_validation instead.

Comment: couldn't you have done `validates_confimation_of :confirmed` in the model?